# How to send Java json Objects to R function?

Tags: java, r, rjava

I want to send json object from JAVA code to R function.
Below is my Java code

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("file", "/home/tejas");
        System.out.printf( "JSON: %s", json.toString() );
        String s="{\"file\":\"/home/tejas\"}";
        REXP valueReturned = c.eval("testMain(\""+map+"\")");
        Object nativeObject=valueReturned.asNativeJavaObject();
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(nativeObject));
```

Here is my R code

```
   testMain <- function(list)
{
library(jsonlite)
return(toJson(list))
}
```

I am getting error as

```
at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.eval(RConnection.java:261)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:36
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related, but the R function is `toJSON()`, not `toJson()`.

Comment: Hola ! it worked by using this line of code **rCon.assign("file",inputParams.get("file"));** before calling external R script